# Newsletter not sending

Tags: newsletter

I have tried sending a newsletter from the newsletter section in Magento but it is not sending. I am new to this stuff so not sure what the issue is. Please help.

Comment: did you get any error ? please provide more details about your issue

Comment: No, I did not get any error. I just made one and put in up to be sent a few minutes later to go out but didn't go out. Just says not sent.

Comment: did you setup email setting in admin?

Comment: I did add an email to the store email addresses or are you talking about different email settings?

Comment: I am talking about smtp email host setting

Comment: Oh those. No I have not touched those yet because I am not sure what to change or what it should be changed to.    Disable Email Communications: No,  Host: localhost, Port (25): 25 and Set Return-Path: No

Comment: where do I do this ->      Step 2 - Enable Gmail Smtp App

 php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content MagePal_GmailSmtpApp
 php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php -f bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: In cmd goto root folder of magento and run php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade this command only

Comment: Sorry that confuses me a bit

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these below step:

1- Check if Magento cron is running by looking into cron_schedule table. There should be resent records for newsletter queue listed in the table and status of the module execution.

2- Run cron service manually by pointing your browser to http://your.magento.url.here/cron.php

3- Enable PHP mail log: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log

4- Check outgoing mail queue on server with mailq command

5- Try to send all mail via external mail server by installing one of the SMTP extensions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

6- Ensure that newsletter messages are not ending up in Spam folders.